# how to count the number of "numbers in for"

Tags: c++, for-loop

everyone, I build a programme to know even and odd number from given numbers.

The even and odd number works just fine, and i want to know the total count of numbers ranging from the start number to the end number but it always says 11 at the output for both.
How do I solve this? and is there any function to count letters/numbers because it will be very helpful.
 I did search it up but I can't find any Thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

    int number;
    int firstNum,secondNum;
    int countOdd,countEven;

    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> firstNum;

   cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    cin >> secondNum;

if (firstNum>secondNum )
    cout << "Sorry the first number must be less than second number";

else

    cout << "Odd numbers in given range are: ";
    for(number = firstNum;number <= secondNum; number++)

         if(number % 2 !=0)
             cout << number<< " ";
     countOdd = number;
     cout << "\nTotal count of odd number is :" << countOdd << endl;

    printf("\nEven numbers in given range are: ");
    for(number = firstNum;number <= secondNum; number++)

         if(number % 2 ==0)
             cout << number << " ";
 countEven = number;
     cout << "\nTotal count of even number is :" << countEven << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"i want to know the total count of numbers ... but it always says 11..."` That's because you enter `11` as `secondNum` and are setting `countOdd = number;` and `countEven = number;` within  your loops. (so what is the final value for `number` before the loop exits?) The computer is doing exactly what you are telling it to do...

Answer (score 2):

Code to count odd and even numbers:

```
using namespace std; 

// Return the number of odd numbers  
// in the range [L, R]  
int countOdd(int L, int R){  

    int N = (R - L) / 2; 

    // if either R or L is odd  
    if (R % 2 != 0 || L % 2 != 0)  
        N += 1; 

    return N; 
} 

// Driver code 
int main() 
{  
    int L = 3, R = 7; 
    int odds = countOdd(L, R);  
    int evens = (R - L + 1) - odds;  

    cout << "Count of odd numbers is " << odds << endl;  
    cout << "Count of even numbers is " << evens << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your counts with every iteration of the for loop. `countOdd = number;` should be moved inside the if statement and read more like this:

```c
if (number % 2 != 0) {
    cout << number << " ";
    countOdd++;
}
```

That way you will actually be counting the numbers as you find them.
This goes the same for the code in the counting of even numbers.

```c
if (number % 2 == 0) {
    cout << number << " ";
    countEven++;
}
```

And don't forget to initialize the counters variables before using them:

```
countOdd = countEven = 0;
```

Comment: You may point out `countOdd` must be initialized as `countOdd = 0;` before entering the loop or *Undefined Behavior* will result. It can be done as part of the loop using the *comma operator* as well, e.g. `for(number = firstNum, countOdd = 0; number <= secondNum; number++) { ... }`